# how to pass auth header in next 14 fetch request using apollo client in server component

Tags: next.js, apollo

i want to pass JWT token in my apollo client in next.js 14 server component, i have follow from guide how to pass but its not working.

Following is apollo setup for data fetching inside server components

```html
import { HttpLink, from } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      )
    );
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_API_URL,
});

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link: from([errorLink, httpLink]),
  });
});
```

I am using next auth, so getting JWT token from next auth then passing to apollo fetch request using context

```html
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { getClient } from "@utils/apolloclient";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import GET_DRAFT_POST from "@/lib/queries/wordpress/GET_DRAFT_POST";
import BlogPage from "@/components/blog/blogpage";
import authOptions from "@utils/auth";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export const metadata = {
  title: "Bingo Card Generator - Create Custom Printable Cards Online",
  description:
    "Discover our interactive bingo card generator. Create custom cards from templates or scratch. Print for live games or share for online fun!",
};

export default async function Page({ params, searchParams }) {
  const postId = searchParams?.id;
  const postType = searchParams?.post_type;

  if (!postId || !postType) {
    notFound();
  }

  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  const token = session?.user?.jwtAuthToken;

  const { data } = await getClient().query({
    query: GET_DRAFT_POST,
    variables: {
      id: postId,
      asPreview: false,
    },
    context: {
      fetchOptions: {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token + "" },
      },
    },
  });

  console.log(data);

  if (!data?.contentNode) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <div className="page-content">
      {postType === "post" && (
        <BlogPage
          post={data.contentNode}
          newsletterSettings={data?.newsletterSettings}
          params={{ slug: data?.contentNode?.slug }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

without auth query firing properly